# Cannot load ag-grid using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I just downloaded the ag-grid and referenced it correctly into my webpage . Followed the JavaScript example listed on the ag-grid website.

I get error ' Cannot set property 'cellRendererMap' of null '
FYI - I am not using any MVC framework.

### What am I doing wrong ? I don't want to make it complex - Its a small POC.

```
<pre>
<html>
<h1> My new Page </h1>
<body>
<span> Hi I am a rockstar </span>

<div id="newGrid" style="height: 100%;width:500px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/rsportal/js/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
    {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
    {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
    ];

    var rowData = [
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
    ];

    var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData
    };

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#newGrid');
        new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
        });
</script>
</body>

</html>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Berangar . Having the class="ag-fresh" solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to remove the DOMContentLoaded handler ?
Your script is already executed when DOM is ready.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/7.2.2/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 100%; height:200px;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
    {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
    {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
];

var rowData = [
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
];

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData
};

    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);

</script>
```

Comment: no doesn't work. It has to do with some missing argument to the method cellRendererMap.